# What was the condition of women in "primitive societies" around the world?

Tags: ancient-history, women, reference, oppression

In [Book I, Chapter IV](https://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/malthus-an-essay-on-the-principle-of-population-vol-1-1826-6th-ed) of "An Essay on the Principle of Population" (6th edition, 1826), Thomas Malthus states how terrible the condition of women was among "savage societies" (to which he meant natives outside "civilised Europe" living mainly of hunting, fishing, and gathering, so excluding established agrarian societies). For instance, he writes:

> It is justly observed by Dr. Robertson, that, "Whether man has been improved by the progress of arts and civilization, is a question which in the wantonness of disputation has been agitated among philosophers. That women are indebted to the refinement of polished manners for a happy change in their state, is a point which can admit of no doubt." **In every part of the world, one of the most general characteristics of the savage is to despise and degrade the female sex.** Among most of the tribes in America their condition is so peculiarly grievous, that servitude is a name too mild to describe their wretched state. A wife is no better than a beast of burden. While the man passes his days in idleness or amusement, the woman is condemned to incessant toil. Tasks are imposed upon her without mercy, and services are received without complacence or gratitude. There are some districts in America where this state of degradation has been so severely felt, that mothers have destroyed their female infants, to deliver them at once from a life in which they were doomed to such a miserable slavery.

This and other chapters contain several recounts by "Western travelers" of such ill-treatment of women by "savages". Whilst all this is certainly relevant anecdotal evidence, **is there more robust evidence (built upon the advances of scientific inquiry and methods since Malthus' times) about the condition of women in these "primitive societies" around the world?** A [dedicated article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women's_history) to the history of women in Wikipedia, for instance, is scarce on ancient history and has many unsupported claims. A book refered there (Women's History and Ancient History) does not really focuses on "primitive societies". In this sense, any reference to particular research and/or books on the topic is most welcomed.

PS1: the term "savages" and "primitive societies" are surely arbitrary. Yet, Malthus had something in mind, which might include groups like hunters and gatherers, nomads, indigenous peoples, and so on. I am not particularly interested on conditioning the terms, but I am definitely not asking about ancient cultures like Egypt, Greek, Roman, Asyrian, Chinese, etc.

PS2: I hope the political correctness police does not immediately judge me as a denier of violence against women. I am not expressing any particular opinion. I am looking for scientifically-based analysis of the topic.

Comment: It's an interesting topic, and an intersting post, but I can't (easily) see what your actually *question* is.

Comment: @ChrisH Updated question :)

Comment: “Savage societies” really isn't a concept lending itself to scientifically-based analysis.

Comment: @Relaxed Definition "clarified".

Comment: Please clarify: Is this about "primitive societies" (all that Mathus would count as such)/("primitive North American Indians" (the poeple he talks about in that instance: and the actual history of women there and then; as you emphasised "in every part of the world"). Ideally, this would be reflected in the Q title as well.

Comment: @LangLangC I am not restricting myself to Native Americans. The book and his examples cover pretty much the whole globe. Q edited.

Comment: @luchonacho I think you've done a great job of framing a difficult question!

Comment: History isn’t a “science,” I think what you’re looking for is “modern scholarly discipline.”

Answer (score 14):

Quite the opposite, he's arguing that "savage" societies give women **higher** status (from our modern point of view).

I think its important to understand that this was written by a man who benefitted from sitting comfortably in the upper rungs of Victorian (technically actually [Georgian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_era)) English society. He's not talking about modern western women with (on paper at least) comparable rights to men, he's talking about *Victorian Women*. This was an era when women had a [very specific and idealized role](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_the_Victorian_era) as essentially the lead domestic in a man's house, but with sexual duties of actually producing the children as well. They had no legal rights to own property, to take anyone to court, and of course not to vote. Effectively, they were the property of men.

This was what people such as Malthus viewed as the natural and rightful place for women, the ideal that should be aspired to, the pinnacle for a woman. Anything that fell far from that pinnacle was considered a "degradation" of the woman.

"Savages" in the English of the day was the word particularly used to describe Native Americans. It is in fact used this way in the [Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript). Different tribes had different cultures and different roles for women, and by-and-large the status of women in Native societies was still lesser to men, but of course anything outside of the Victorian ideal of the status of women (eg: being expected to do non-household labor, have their own possessions, or having political say) Malthus would have considered a "degradation".

One thing in particular that tended to drive Europeans nuts was the typical American cultural quirk that [farming was considered "women's work"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00287408). This is likely what he's referring to with his "beast of burden" comment. A large amount of the "civilizing" mission of the US BIA was to get Native American men to do their own farming (which of course the native men in question looked at as an attempt to effectively make them women), and it was still trying to do this well into the 20th century.

Here's a quote I found from an 1827 Norwalk, Ohio newspaper talking about the Osages that expands on exactly what English-speaking society meant by "degraded".

> And their condition is truly degraded; for while the man are _____ing
>   at their ease in their camps, striking or telling stories, or engaged
>   in the sport of war, or of hunting; the females have to build their
>   houses, plant their corn, dress the skins, transport the baggage, and
>   wood, and water, and bear a many a heavy burden.

Of course looking at this with modern eyes, he's basically reciting the identity function: The less European a society, the less European its women behave.

Comment: Also, as far as the "man passes his days in idleness and amusement", hunting in those cultures was typically not recreation, but an important job that had to be done.  In Mathus's time and class, hunting was a diversion.

Comment: @DavidThornley - Wow, how did I miss that part? Yeah, that could have been transcribed directly into the old BIA's mission documents. Men's work for Native American nations was typically hunting, trade, and war. European colonizers felt (with some justification) that if they could make the men do the farming, they'd have much less spare time on their hands to be making war (on European settlers). And of course the natives weren't idiots, and knew that's exactly what was behind it as well. Essentially emasculating the whole tribe.

Comment: Thanks. Some reference to literature would be better. It's certainly an interesting lecture of the issue, but could well look like an opinion. Also, you seem to forget the issue of infanticide and violence against women, that he mentions there and elsewhere.

Comment: @luchonacho - This answer concentrates on the misunderstanding of Malthus, and as such I can't really comment on material that wasn't included directly in the question. Infanticide really needs its own question, as its a huge topic and perhaps a bad assumption that Victorian (or Modern society) was of one mind about it within themselves even.

Comment: @T.E.D. Actually that was included directly in the question and Malthus: "that mothers have destroyed their female infants" and "This and other chapters contain several recounts by 'Western travelers' of such ill-treatment of women by 'savages'."

Comment: I didn't say the infanticide bit wasn't included, but the other. All that's in the question about "ill-treatment" is an assurance that there would be quotes about anecdotes to include if the author felt like it. I will say here that what appears to be described is some anecdotes, and its a truism that **the plural of "anecdote" is not "data"**. Its quite possible some Native Americans visiting England returned to their homes with similar horror tales about ill-treatment of English women by English men, particularly when you consider their standards for acceptable female behavior didn't mesh.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not disagreeing with the answer, nor with the general principle expressed, but, it may be to apodictically, [it's not an absolute, (really: often especially for historians??](http://blog.danwin.com/don-t-forget-the-plural-of-anecdote-is-data/) (https://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/11/10/the-plural-of-anecdote-is-data/)

Comment: You seem to be implying that in "savage societies" women were better off in every dimension. You haven't provided evidence about it. Just merely suggesting the bias of Malthus (and others) position. But the extent of the bias is the important issue here. Was it sufficiently enough such that women were better off in every dimension, or they were still ill-treated but not to such a great point as suggested by Malthus? The question remains unanswered.

Comment: @luchonacho - Didn't say that at all. From a history perspective we can't really deal in "better". Values change. But what rights people do or do not have is fairly easily quantifyable. There have certainly been societies in history that gave women less rights than the pre-modern English. (Can't come up with one off the top of my head, but it seems very likely. Might be a good question for someone).

Comment: Is that underscore ellipsis censorship or a simple brainf___? (But then again, my own new church also told me to recline from sloths…)

Comment: @LangLangC - Its a direct quote. Presumably that part was unreadable for some reason in the original source. I tried to find another source for the article that might have that bit filled in, but had no luck. But you can tell from context its something along the lines of "sitting" or "resting".

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=CqxVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA788&dq=And+their+condition+is+truly+degraded;+for+while+the+man+are&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9huyDza7hAhVO3RoKHfI8C58Q6AEIKjAA

Comment: @T.E.D - not just a "typical American cultural quirk" about farming. In large parts of Africa, farming is frequently considered "women's work". More broadly, I'm not sure we can generalise about the position of women in **all** "primitive" /pre-urban societies.

Comment: @TheHonRose - Of course not. Fortunately, I think we can establish that the quote was talking specifically about Native Americans (and likely North American ones).

Comment: @LangLangC - Interesting. That looks like the same text alright, but from a different source and attributing it to a different source. Either I'm misreading, or someone was plagiarizing someone else.